# Ruby | Change variable reference to nil

Tags: ruby, reference

I have the following scenario:

```rb
# Keeps track of all `HomeMadeObject` objects
obj_list = []

# A 2-dimensional matrix of either `nil` or `HomeMadeObject` elements
matrix = ...

# I then add an object like so.
obj = HomeMadeObject.new
matrix[y][x] = obj
obj_list.push(obj)

# Later on, I need to remove 'that same object' from the `matrix`.
matrix[y][x] = nil
```

When I set `matrix[y][x]` to `nil`, this will also affect **the same object** in the `obj_list`, making it also `nil` in the `obj_list`.

```rb
puts obj_list[0] # nil
```

---

What I'd like to do is to change the `matrix[y][x]` **pointer**'s location (or the *reference*) so that the `matrix[y][x]` points to the `nil` object. In that way, `obj_list` points to all the correct objects and the `matrix` cells can address different locations without overriding a `HomeMadeObject` object by `nil` (creating `nil` elements in `obj_list`).

## Edit

I would like to update the objects in `obj_list` and see the updates in the `matrix` (so I need to have some kind of a reference here to the original object). But When a `HomeMadeObject` isn't needed anymore in the `matrix`, I want to remove it only from the `matrix`.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to understand here is, In Ruby all variables and constants store references to objects. That’s why one can’t copy the content by assigning one variable to another variable. Variables of type Object in Java or pointers to objects in C++ are good to think of. However, you can’t change the value of each pointer itself.

So use dup method when you are pushing into the object list, your problem is solved.

```
obj_list.push(obj.dup)
```

Comment: What if I want to be able to modify the objects in the `obj_list` and see the updates in the `matrix`? I'm new to **Ruby** :')